# Inserir HTML em Link dentro de Div automaticamente com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um código HTML, onde no mesmo tem um link em uma imagem. Este link é criado por um painel de controle e não é possível colocar um `ID` ou uma `Classe` nele. Porém a imagem com o link fica dentro de uma `div` que tem o `ID` com nome `popup-imagem`.

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar `data-popup-open="popup-1"` dentro do link através de `jQuery`, e se for possível, como faço isto?

### Código Atual:

```
<div id="popup-imagem">
    <a href="#"><img src="imagem.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

### Como eu gostaria que ficasse:

```
<div id="popup-imagem">
    <a href="#" data-popup-open="popup-1"><img src="imagem.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) do jQuery:

```
$("#popup-imagem > a").attr("data-popup-open","popup-1");
```

`> a` seleciona os elementos `a` onde o pai é `popup-imagem`.

A sintaxe dele é: `.attr( attributeName, value )`, onde o primeiro argumento é o nome do atributo e o segundo o valor. O primeiro sempre é uma string, enquanto o segundo pode ser uma string, um número ou nulo.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#popup-imagem" ).find( "a" ).attr("data-popup-open", "popup-1")
```

Veja mais em:

https://api.jquery.com/find/

http://api.jquery.com/attr/